# How do I make my program only react to yes or no answers?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I'd be able to make my program reply to unknown answers that arent yes or no questions, when I ask them their name and they respond, they can say it is their name or its not and are given the chance to retype it until they confirm that is their name(test my code to see what I mean) but when it re asks them what their name is and says "oh, so your name is?" it just looks like the computer skips past their response and asks the question again, but i want the program to say "sorry i don't understand that"  THEN re ask the question. Now what I'm wondering is how I can make it to where the computer responds with an error message to there wrong or misunderstood answer

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;
string Name;
}
int main() {
    double age;
    cout << "what is your name?"<< endl;
    getline(cin, Name);
    cout << "your name is " << Name << "?, is that correct? Y/N"<< endl;
    string answer;
    getline(cin, answer);
    if (answer == "yes") {
        cout << "thanks for the information" << endl;
    }
     if (answer == "no"){
         do {
             cout << "oh ok, what is your name then?"<< endl;
             getline(cin,Name);
             cout<< "oh so your name is " + Name << "? Y/N"<< endl;
             getline(cin, answer);
         }
         while(answer <= "no");{

         }

    }

    cout << "how old are you?" << endl;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "your name is "<< Name << " and you are " << age << " years old"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your C++ textbook should have an explanation that the `if` statement, which your program uses, also has an optional `else` part, that you can use to do exactly what you want to do. Is there anything in your textbook's explanation of this that's unclear to you?

Comment: `while(answer <= "no")` probably doesn't do what you want. I'd guess you'd want `while(answer != "yes")`.

Comment: Please do not ask for private tutoring. The idea of StackOverflow is NOT to help individuals, but to make a collection of Q/A pairs which are helpful for everyone. 1 on 1 sessions are counterproductive to that goal. If you have more suitable questions please ask them by creating more questions here. Otherwise books and tutorial, maybe a tutor are your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using "if" statements and "while" loops. You just need to improve your understanding of the *while* loop & *if-else* statements, then with a few edits you can get your code working.

Firstly, you are prompting the user for "Y/N", but then you are trying to test for "yes" or "no". This is will be very confusing for the user, who is trying to enter a 'Y' or a 'N' and not getting anywhere. You should pick one or the other. In this case I will assume you want to proceed with "Y/N".

First, take a look at your use of the *while* loop.

1. For the *while* condition, you have used a <= sign, which is testing for "less than or equal to". In this context, you probably want to test for equality (==) or non-equality (!=).
2. You haven't placed any statements within the body of the *while* loop (i.e. inside the curly braces {} ). A *while* loop will only execute the code within the curly braces.

For your program, you only need to re-prompt the user if they answer with anything other than a 'Y'. Then you want to keep prompting the user until they enter a 'Y'... a *while* loop is perfect for this. To make this work, your condition for the loop should be (assuming you want to test for upper and lower case input):

```
while (answer != "y" || answer != "Y") {
}
```

Now, any code you put inside the curly braces {} will continue to loop until the user inputs 'y' or "Y".

Next, have a look at your use of *if* statements.
Your first *if* statement tests the input for "yes".
Your second *if* statement tests the input for "no".
The problem with this, is that if neither "yes" or "no" are input, no code will be executed.
The key is changing your second "if" statement to an "else". The "else" will act as a catch all - if anything is entered outside of the program's scope, the *else* statement will catch it and re-prompt the user..

Finally you want to place the if-else statements inside the while loop - then you can be sure the user will continue to be prompted until they enter a 'Y'.

I have altered your code so that it now provides the desired behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    string name {};
    getline (cin, name);
    
    cout << "Your name is: " << name << ". Is that correct? Y/N: " << endl;
    string answer {};
    getline(cin, answer);
    
    while (answer != "y" && answer != "Y") {
        if (answer == "n" || answer == "N") {
            cout << "Oh, ok, what is your name then? " << endl;
            getline (cin, name);
            cout << "Oh, so your name is " << name << "? Y/N: " << endl;
            getline (cin, answer);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Sorry... I don't understand that. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'..." << endl;
            cout << "Your name is: " << name << ". Is that correct? Y/N: " << endl;
            getline (cin, answer);
        }
    }
    
    cout << "How old are you? " << endl;
    int age {};
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Thanks, so your name is "<< name << " and you are " << age << " years old" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```